# Touch a file and give it an icon image via command line

Tags: command-line, files, icons

Imagine this situation: for a given task, at some point of it, I should be able to create an empty file, which I can achieve by `touch file.ext` on the command line. However, if I touch a .jpg file, and open its folder via graphical interface, I'm going to see the default image icon. This icon gives a visual hint that the file is an image.

But I'd like to set an special icon for these files I'm creating. I'd like something like `touch fake-empty-image.jpg --set-icon=/path/to/my-custom-icon.jpg`

Is this something possible to do?

Many thanks.

Comment: That would entirely depend on what is showing your custom icon. An XDG compliant program? In which case it would need to be done in the .desktop file.

Comment: Which icon is showed for a file is a parameter defined on the GUI (Gnome, KDE, xfce, etc.) . The first thing to do is define which GUI will be used.

Comment: Thanks, folks. I had to have a different approach for each different GUI. In the end, we decided to leave that only for Apple's MacOs users, for which we had to create . (dot) folder.